# NHibernate and assigning ID before saving entity to database

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to have ID assigned to an entity, before saving it to the database. I've been using HiLo generator, but the ID is assigned after I call the session.Save(object). Here how it looks like:

```cs
var std1 = new Student
{
    FirstName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    LastName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};

//--- I need to have unique Id assigned here, after the object construction.

Console.WriteLine($">>> StudentId before {std1.ID} Name {std1.FirstName}");
Console.WriteLine("<press enter>");
Console.ReadLine();
session.Save(std1);

//--- I'm getting Id assigned only after calling Save, which is too late for the purposes I need

Console.WriteLine($">>> StudentId after {std1.ID}");
```

Here is how Student entity class definition looks like:

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="CSharpTests" namespace="CSharpTests">

    <class name="Student" table="student">
        <id name="ID" column="id">
            <generator class="hilo">
                <param name="table">students_hilo</param>
                <param name="column">next_hi</param>
                <param name="max_lo">100</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="LastName" column="last_name" type="String"/>
        <property name="FirstName" column="first_name" type="String"/>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Is there a way to assign that Id before session.Save()?

Comment: `session.Save` doesn’t save the object in the database but saves/registers it with the session. Therefore if you need the Id earlier just put the save earlier. The object is only saved in the database when you commit your transaction.

Comment: I'm assuming the `Student` id is some form of integer? Could it become a `Guid`? You could assign each instance its own id at construction: `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Comment: i don't understand in witch situation would you need to get the id BEFORE saving ?